# sed find pattern then join lines

Tags: unix, sed, solaris

I'm looking for some help on a problem with a data file i keep seeing

The data file looks like this when it contains errors

```
H Data  data    data
R data  datadata    datadatadata^M
  data  data    ^M
datadata
R data  datadata    datadatadata    data    data    datadata
R data  datadata    datadatadata    ^M
data    data    datadata
R data  datadata    datadatadata    data    data    datadata
T data  data    data    data
```

i need to remove the ^M characters and join the following lines to the data file would like this and every line should start with either H,R or T.

```
H Data  data    data
R data  datadata    datadatadata    data    data    datadata
R data  datadata    datadatadata    data    data    datadata
R data  datadata    datadatadata    data    data    datadata
R data  datadata    datadatadata    data    data    datadata
T data  data    data    data
```

I know the real answer is to fix the underlying data but that is not an option at the minute and im looking for a workaround.

thanks in advance

Joe

Comment: does `tr -d '\r' < file > outFile` help you? Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

```
sed -i your file 's/^M$/R//g'
```

or

```
sed 's/^M$/R//g' oldfile >newfile ; mv newfile oldfile
```

So that removes the dos characters and replace it with a R. that was a quick thought mybe there is a better solution for it.

Comment: Thanks for the response but does not resolve the issue, the data on the lines that have the ^M have been split from the lines above so i need to move these up rather than just add an R to the line.

Answer (score 0):

```
sed 's/\n^M//g' YourFile
```

or

```
sed 's/[[:cntrl:]]//g' YourFile
```

ps: ^M = Ctrl + M

Answer (score 0):

```
 sed '/\r$/ { N; s/\r\n//; }' infile > outfile
```

Note: This hinges on `sed` understanding control chars. such as `\r`, which works on Linux - not sure about Solaris; note that `^M` is another representation of `\r` (CR).

What it does:

- For lines ending in `\r`, command `N` appends a `\n` and the *next* line to the current line.
- The `s` command then effectively removes the resulting `\r\n` sequence from the two joined lines by replacing it with an empty string.

Answer (score 0):

first convert your file using the `dos2unix` tool

```
dos2unix filename

sed -i filename 's/^M$/R//g'
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed ':a;$!N;s/\r\n//;ta;P;D' file
```

If you want to turn spaces into tabs, use:

```
sed ':a;$!N;s/\r\n//;ta;s/  */\t/g;P;D' file
```